# How does this script know who 'currentPlayer' is?

Tags: scripting, roblox

I am new to Roblox development but wanted to try my hand at making an Asteroids game. I started by creating the seat for the spaceship, but I recognized some behavior I can't explain and hoped someone could provide some clarification.

Here is the code I am talking about, just something really basic so I can get the hang of some of the starting ideas:

```
--Services--
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

--Local Variables--
local seat = script.Parent                          -- Refers to the VehicleSeat object
local currentPlayer = nil                           -- Prevents errors in reference to nil?
local prompt = script.Parent.GetInPrompt            -- Get the parent object's proximity prompt

--Proximity Prompt Trigger Code--
prompt.Triggered:Connect(function(currentPlayer) -- Bind the prompt trigger to function
    local char = currentPlayer.Character            -- Get the currentPlayer
    seat:Sit(char.Humanoid)                     -- Make them sit
    prompt.Enabled = false                          -- Disable the prompt so it isn't visible
    print("Character is sitting")                   -- Print to console for debug
end)

--Get up function--
local function gettingUp(currentPlayer)
    print("Attribute Change Fired - Getting Up")    -- Print to console for debug
    prompt.Enabled = true
end

-- Note that since Lua is an interpreted language any function must be defined before use--
seat.ChildRemoved:Connect(function()
    gettingUp(currentPlayer)
end)
```

I see that I access the "Players" service at the top, and I initialize the currentPlayer variable to nil. I don't understand how currentPlayer changes from nil to the player when the proximityPrompt fires.

I thought it could be a 'reserved name' in Roblox, but I can't find any proof of that online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is confusing local variables with function arguments.

At the top of your script, you have defined the local variable, `currentPlayer`. The [ProximityPrompt.Triggered](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/ProximityPrompt/Triggered) signal provides the instance of the [Player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player) that activated it as a function argument. You have named that argument `currentPlayer` also. When in the scope of this function, the function argument is shadowing the local variable, meaning that `currentPlayer` refers to this function argument, not the local variable that you defined at the top of the script.

To avoid this kind of confusion, it's often good practice to name function arguments and local variables different things.

If you want `currentPlayer` to reference the Player that interacted with the ProximityPrompt, try assigning the function argument to the local variable :

```
prompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    currentPlayer = player
    local char = currentPlayer.Character
    seat:Sit(char.Humanoid)
    prompt.Enabled = false
    print("Character is sitting")
end)
```

This will allow your later functions to keep the reference to the Player object.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I have a few more questions. So the actual player isn't instantiated outside the event handler? We define currentPlayer as nil so that we can use that variable outside the Triggered event handler function scope, as you show in your example? Are all player interactions managed and passed to connect blocks through services like Player, and if so, is that defined in an API? Thank you again for your time and guidance.

Comment: A Player is created/instantiated as soon as they join the server. The Players service lets you observe this happening with the Players.PlayerAdded event. The Player exists until the person leaves the server. You don't have to rely on signals exposed on objects and services to get access to these Player objects, you could find the Player as a child of the Players service. Those signals just tend to be a rather efficient method to do so. If you want to learn more about the Roblox API, take a look at the links I posted in my answer, they will take you to the official engine documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your help!